# Ubuntu Server 19.04 systemd service for PixArk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, systemd

I have created a systemd service for a PixArk server on my Ubuntu server that will keep the server running even if it crashes and allow for safe shutdown of the server when the system is restarted or powered off. The code is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=PixArk SilentMecha
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/PixArk
Type=forking
User=mecha

Restart=always

ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -S PixArk -d -m ./start_server.sh

ExecStop=/PixArk/rconcli/rcon-cli --config /PixArk/PixArk.yaml "ServerChat SERVER SHUTTING DOWN IN 15 SECONDS..."
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStop=/PixArk/rconcli/rcon-cli --config /PixArk/PixArk.yaml "ServerChat SERVER SHUTTING DOWN IN 10 SECONDS..."
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStop=/PixArk/rconcli/rcon-cli --config /PixArk/PixArk.yaml "ServerChat SERVER SHUTTING DOWN IN 5 SECONDS..."
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStop=/PixArk/rconcli/rcon-cli --config /PixArk/PixArk.yaml "saveworld"
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 1
ExecStop=/PixArk/rconcli/rcon-cli --config /PixArk/PixArk.yaml "DoExit"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The start_server.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
wine64 /PixArk/ShooterGame/Binaries/Win64/PixARKServer.exe CubeWorld_Light?DelayRegisterServer=True?bRawSockets=True?SessionName="SilentMecha"?MaxPlayers=20?RCONEnabled=True?RCONPort=27017? -server -gameplaylogging -log -CULTUREFORCOOKING=en -NoBattlEye -QueryPort=27016 -Port=27015 -CubePort=27018 -cubeworld=SilentMecha -NoHangDetection
```

I have it working. It starts and everything however when I run the command `sudo systemctl stop PixArk` it hangs for a very long time then the command finishes. I have created an exact same service for my Minecraft server and it completes as soon as it finishes the last ExecStop command. Is there something I am missing? Please can someone assist me in this as I am not an expert at working with systemd yet. It does stop but it takes longer than with the minecraft server for it to return back to the shell before you can do another command.

So if I run the commands by hand I get everything to complete in 20 seconds. When run in with systemd `sudo systemctl stop PixArk` it takes about a minute to two minutes before it returns to the terminal. The reason why I am trying to find the fault is because how it is supposed to work is safely stop the PixArk server before turning off the system. If it takes to long to complete then I fear it will increase the shutdown sequence by 2 minutes longer than in should. It isn't currently a major issue but I would like to just find where my error is. Maybe I am missing something simple.

Comment: This may be related to the fact that systemd will keep all processes launched by the service in a control group and when stopping the service it will wait for all processes in that group to finish. See description of `KillMode` option in https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html. After you execute your stop commands manually, try checking if the processes are still running and how much time they need to terminate.

Comment: Thank you. So the screen window that the server is running in closes but the command is still running for at least 30 seconds long after the screen window has been terminated. Is there a cleaner and better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Would it be best to use `KillMode=process` for my specific systemd service? I kill the screen session with ExecStop